# Script To Tick all Boxes using Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I am using the script below to tick all checkboxes on chrome (Dev Console), within the exception to not selec few boxes.

It does work on chrome and tick the boxes I needed, but when I hit submit nothing happens because its mandatory to select the boxes and looks like it not really selecting them and parsing it.

The only error message I see on the console even before to use the script is:

WebSocket connection to xyz.example.com failed.

I have tried on firefox as well with the same outcome.

```
// Find all checkboxes on the page
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

// Define the texts to exclude
var excludedTexts = ['Firewall_Rule_Example_1'];

// Loop through each checkbox and check it, except for the checkboxes with the specified exact texts
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
  var label = checkbox.nextElementSibling;
  
  if (label && excludedTexts.includes(label.textContent.trim())) {
    continue; // Skip the checkboxes with the excluded texts
  }
  
  checkbox.checked = true; // Check the other checkboxes
}
```

Tick the wanted boxes, it is ticking the boxes but when i hit submit on the form it completely ignores what was selected and not going forwarding as the selection is mandatory.

Comment: Maybe the page you are using this on doesn't perform a "normal" form submission, but does it via JavaScript - and the collection of the checked boxes happens via click, input or change event handlers added to those ...

Comment: It probably wants you to dispatch a `change` event on each element explicitly: checkbox.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}))

Comment: I think you are right, just accepts manually clicking on it. Is there way I can get it working via script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger the change event:

```
checkbox.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
```